# How to use Hive to store data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm learning flutter and I'd like to make a simple todo app.

In the app you can create different "lists" (for example "Homework", "groceries"...) and each list consists of list of tasks, so I have to classes:

1. Task (to store a single task)

- String task
- bool completed

2. TaskList (to store a list, made up of tasks)

- String listname
- List tasks (consisting of Tasks)

I used a List made up of TaskLists with some data when I was testing it, but now I want to store the data to the device and I came across Hive, which is based on the idea of "boxes", but I'm not sure how I should approach this.

*Should I create a new box for every new list (and then delete it, when the user deletes the list) or somehow store all the data in a single box?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it makes more sense to have a single box with all the tasks. Then when the user deletes a task you just remove the task at the corresponding key of the box and you're good to go.

Each box needs to be initialized or "opened" on app start. So trying to add boxes dynamically would unnecessarily complicate the code you need to write, without any additional benefits.